# Fourier transform of tempered distribution

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions, fourier-transform

I'm wondering whether anyone knows a reference or proof for finding the Fourier transform of $f(t):=(t+1)^{1/2}t_+^{1/2}$? (Here $t_+=\max (t,0)$.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\tfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{i\omega t}dt=\tfrac{1}{2}\pi\delta(\omega)+\tfrac{1}{2}i\omega^{-1}$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}te^{i\omega t}dt=-i\frac{d}{d\omega}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{i\omega t}dt=-i\pi\frac{d}{d\omega}\delta(\omega)-\omega^{-2}$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}[\sqrt{t(1+t)}-t-\tfrac{1}{2}]e^{i\omega t}dt=\omega^{-2}-\tfrac{1}{2}i\omega^{-1}+\tfrac{1}{2}i\omega^{-1}e^{-i\omega/2}K_{1}(-i\omega/2)
$$
adding these three results gives the required Fourier transform
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{t(1+t)}e^{i\omega t}dt=\tfrac{1}{2}\pi\delta(\omega)-i\pi\frac{d}{d\omega}\delta(\omega)+\tfrac{1}{2}i\omega^{-1}e^{-i\omega/2}K_{1}(-i\omega/2)
$$
with $K_1$ a modified Bessel function of the second kind; the derivative of the Dirac delta function should be understood in the context of an integral,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\omega)\frac{d}{d\omega}\delta(\omega)d\omega=-\lim_{\omega\rightarrow 0}\frac{d}{d\omega}f(\omega)$$

Comment: what's your reference for the second integral, the one with the Bessel function?

Comment: The second integral is the output of Mathematica, with the condition ${\rm Im}\,\omega>0$. Since the integrand decays as $1/t$ for large $t$, this condition can be extended to ${\rm Im}\,\omega\geq 0$.

Comment: Alternatively, it can be justified by referring to one of the integral representations for $K_1$. Like this one: http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E8

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker: I'm sorry but I'm not sure why the fact that the integrand decays as $1/t$ implies that the formula remains true also for $\operatorname{Im}\omega =0$? Doesn't the integral diverge for $\operatorname{Im}\omega =0$?

Comment: @Alex A: $\int_0^{\infty}t^{-1}\sin(\omega t)dt=\pi/2\times{\rm sign}(\omega)$ for $\omega$ real; similarly, the integral that decays as $t^{-1}\cos\omega t$ is finite. OK?

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker: I'm not quite sure how to motivate the second identity (with the difference $\sqrt{t(1+t)} - t$) rigorously (without using Mathematica) for instance by using integral representations as mentioned by Igor. Any idea?

Comment: @Carlo Beenaker: After a closer look it doesn't seem as if the difference $\sqrt{t(1+t)} - t$ decays as $1/t$ but rather behaves like $1/2 + \mathcal{O}(1/t)$ when $t$ is large.

Comment: @Alex A: you are right, my mistake, I have corrected it; the final answer now contains an extra term $(\pi/2)\delta(\omega)$

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker: Again, looking at the integral with the difference in it, can we be sure there is not supposed to be a some $\delta $ (and a derivative thereof) on the right hand side? I would somehow like to do that calculation without using Mathematica.

Comment: well, yes, we can be sure because it does now properly decay as $1/t$

Comment: Yes, but if $\omega = 0$ I suppose there is still a problem with the convergence.

Comment: But it really doesn't matter as I'm interested in the transform only for $\omega \ne 0$. I was just curious.